# edit page with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am building a feature similar to the page customization feature of pagemodo.com. The user has to click on a label(div) in a HTML page and a CKEDITOR will load in a separate div with the label text.

Now, the ckeditor is loading with the label text but the "KeyUp" event of CKEDITOR is not firing. Only if the "KeyUp" event fires, I would be able to call another function "readAsTyped" to change the text in the label simultaneously.

You can see the working copy here http://graffiti-media.co/testing/rashmi/custom/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.editable').click(function(){
        $(this).children().each(function(index, domEle) {
                createEditor($(domEle).text(), domEle);
            });
        });

    });

    var editor, html = '';


    function createEditor(text1, domEle)
    {

        // Create a new editor inside the <div id="editor">, setting its value to html
        var config = {};
        ckeditor_instance = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'editor', config, text1 );

        var abc=ckeditor_instance.name;
        ckeditor_instance.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
                e.editor.on('contentDom', function() {

                e.editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
                    // keyup event in ckeditor

                readAsTyped($('#cke_editor2'),$(domEle));
                    //on focus
                }
            );
        });
    }); 
    }


function readAsTyped(obj, label) {
    var typedVal = obj.val();
    // set the value of characters into the label
    $(label).html(typedVal);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?
http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/recipe-live-preview-of-ckeditor.html

Comment: Yeah, Something similar to this. There is only a small difference. When a div is clicked, a CKEDITOR is opened for each child inside the div. In your example, there is only one CKEDITOR instance in the page hence we can bind the events like this "CKEDITOR.on()". I need to bind events for multiple CKEDITORs in the same page.

Comment: You can bind the events to every instance with CKEDITOR when they are created or individually to each instance according to your needs.

Comment: This is the code I am using right now. I am appending a CKEDITOR instance to the div and assigning it to a variable "ckeditor_instance " but the "instanceCreated" event is never firing.                                             `ckeditor_instance = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'editor', config, text1 );
 ckeditor_instance.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
    document.getElementById( e.editor.name + '_preview').innerHTML = e.editor.getData();
    e.editor.on('change', function (ev) {
        document.getElementById( ev.editor.name + '_preview').innerHTML = ev.editor.getData();
    });
});`

Comment: A CKEditor instance doesn't fire such "instanceCreated" event: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html that event is fired only by the global CKEDITOR object http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#event:instanceCreated